# Pass error from Rails to iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift

I raise error from Rails via API with this code:

```
render :json => { :error => "Something went wrong, server error" }, :status => 420
```

I'd like to display the error message "Something went wrong, server error" directly in iOS (Swift). I use simple AFNetworking v2's `AFHTTPSessionManager` to handle API request/response. In the `error: NSError` object in the `failure` block, I don't see the message from the server. What should I do?

```
let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = AFHTTPSessionManager.POST(
    url,
    parameters: params,
    success: { (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        NSLog("POST Success -> \(url)")
        completion(task: task, response: responseObject as! NSDictionary!, error: nil)
    },
    failure: { (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) in
        NSLog("POST Error -> \(url)")
        completion(task: task, response: nil, error: error)
    }
)
```

UPDATE:

I think it has to do with Rails rather than iOS. According to this article: http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/04/rendering-errors-in-json-with-rails/, it recommended `render :json => { :error => error.to_s }, :status => 420`,

but when I look at the response object from Rails, I see something like this:

```
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Vary"=>"Accept-Encoding", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "X-Request-Id"=>"461503cb-61e8-466e-a13f-09eeaa004240", "X-Runtime"=>"0.007684", "Content-Length"=>"86"}
#<ActionDispatch::Response::RackBody:0x007fb7989d31c0>
```

In Rails, I can access the message via `JSON.parse(response.body)['error']`, how do I do so in iOS?

Comment: What's the value of `error.localizedDescription`?

Comment: I get this error: `"Request failed: client error (420)"`

Comment: I added some updated info, thanks @AdamPro13